# HTML5 input type=color onChange event does not fire when the color is modified

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML5** `input type=color` . The issue is when I attach onchange event, it only fires when the color is modified and saved, but not when it is modified.

I'm looking for an event that fires as I change the colors real time, and not when I close the color picker and save it.

```js
const triggerme = (id) => {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="clrPicker" onchange="triggerme(this.id)">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: 1) Not jquery related.  2) Use the `input` event

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome

Comment: It works after you save the color picker. I want this to fire as I change colors.

Comment: Even input event does not fire when from the color picker window.

Comment: @KarthikD it is indeed firing as you are changing between colors. At least in Chrome, your snippet is working fine.

Comment: You cant save color as you change the color by the way you do this. You need to use a plugin instead or do it by yourself.

Comment: @KarthikD which browser are you using?

Comment: Working as expected for me as well

Comment: I tried this on Chrome and Chromium browsers (electron). Let me make it clear that the event fires only after I exit the color picker, but not when I'm on the color picker choosing different colors. Thanks again!

Comment: Your requirement is based on browser internals, which is less consistent. Use plugin like https://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/.

Comment: I wanted to try and do this in native javascript or jquery if possible, before using any plugins.  Functionality wise, I think its fair to expect that the user might want to see how the selected color applies before saving it. So I thought there should be an event available that fires before saving

Comment: @KarthikD what do you mean by 'save' ??

Comment: @AkashJain - I mean, when you open the color picker, select a color, and then save. It fires. But when you open the color picker, keep changing different colors to try out which one looks good, it does not fire. This is what I meant. Hope I'm explaining it clearly.

Comment: When clicking around without saving you're within the browser's/OS color picker and no event is sent to the browser until the control has been closed. I don't believe there's any way to capture what you want without a custom plugin.

Comment: @j08691 - Thanks for your comment. I just wanted to check if there is an event for this. If there is none, then I might have to look into custom plugins. Any suggestions which are lightweight and easy to implement?

Comment: For anyone who wants to use a plugin, I found this plugin to be light weight and easy to implement. 
https://tovic.github.io/color-picker/#section:extend

Answer (score 1):

For live preview, use the oninput event.

You can check this example:

https://codeburst.io/color-switcher-ui-with-color-input-type-css-variables-d4efd8aa6f8f